# Free theory generating functional

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, propagator

The generating functional for a real scalar field theory is given by
$$
\mathcal{Z}[J] = \int\mathcal{D}\phi \exp\left(i\int{d^4x(\mathcal{L}+J(x)\phi(x)})\right)
$$
How can I show that for a free field theory:$$
\mathcal{L}_0  =-\frac{1}{2}(\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi+m^2\phi^2)
$$
the generating functional is given by:
$$
\mathcal{Z}_0[J]=Z_0[J=0]\exp\left(\frac{i}{2}\int{d^4xd^4yJ(x)D(x-y)J(y)} \right).
$$
When I substitute in $\mathcal{Z}[J]$  I get the following:
$$
\mathcal{Z}_0[J]=\int{\mathcal{D\phi}\exp{\left(i\int{d^4x(-\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi-m^2\phi^2}+J(x)\phi(x))\right)}}.
$$
I don't really know how to proceed from here.

Edit:
First I tried substituting for(integration by parts got me here)
$$
\int{d^4x}\left[\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi)(\partial^\mu\phi)-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2\right]=\int{d^4x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\phi(-\partial^2-m^2)\phi+J\phi\right)
$$
the shifted field
$$
\phi' = \phi - i\int{d^4x}D_F(x-y)J(y)
$$
which gives
$$
\int{d^4x}\left[{\frac{1}{2}\phi'(-\partial^2-m^2)}\phi'+\frac{1}{2}\phi'(-\partial^2-m^2)i\int{d^4y}D_F(x-y)J(y)+i\frac{1}{2}\int{d^4x}D_F(x-y)J(y)(-\partial^2-m^2)\phi'+i\frac{1}{2}\int{d^4y}D_F(x-y)J(y)(-\partial^2-m^2)i\int{d^4y}D_F(x-y)J(y)+J(x)\phi'+i\int{d^4y}J(x)D_F(x-y)J(y)\right]
$$

Now we use the fact that $D_F$ is a Green's function of the Klein-Gordon operator, (ie. $(\partial^2-m^2)D(x-y)=i\delta(x-y)$ and we cancel out 3 terms. What happens with the $$
i\frac{1}{2}\int{d^4y}D_F(x-y)J(y)(-\partial^2-m^2)i\int{d^4y}D_F(x-y)J(y)
$$
term? Did I made a mistake somewhere or is it just zero? and why?

Comment: That's an (infinite dimensional) Gaussian integral, so it can be evaluated by completing the square.

Comment: This is worked out explicitly in Peskin and Schroeder section 9.2.

Comment: Integrate by parts and then complete the square.

Comment: Use the defining eq of the green function, acting with your derivative through the y integral!